# Загрузка XML разметки в фоне

Tags: java, android, ui

Добрый вечер! Имеется цель во время отображения первой активности (экрана загрузки) подгрузить вторую разметку в фоне, чтобы приложение не пыталось парсить разметку и, из-за этого, тормозить.

Существует ли в Android'e какой-то метод пропарсить разметку в фоне, а когда активность начнет открываться, прорисовать уже загруженный вариант разметки?

---

Нашел такой вариант на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/312516/), но он не дает возможность отобразить процесс загрузки, только фотографию. С ним все ясно, но есть ли другие варианты (даже если они противоречат [гайдлайнам](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/launch-screens.html))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Навскидку вижу 2 способа загрузки разметки в фоне:

1. Загружать разметку с помощью `LayoutInflater`, поместив вызов `LayoutInflater.inflate()` в `Handler/Thread` и потом уже показать полученную вьюшку
2. Загрузку делать через `AsyncLayoutInflater` (доступно только с API>=24)

Comment: Интересный подход. Никогда не задумывался, что `inflate` можно делать в фоне, а потом уже готовую вьшку устанавливать.

Comment: Я тоже не задумывался об этом, ваш вопрос меня подвел к этой мысли

Answer (score -1):

Можно внутри одного экрана (Активити), внутри одной разметки, разместить все необходимое, включая экран загрузки. Тогда приложение будет тормозить на отображении экрана загрузки, загрузке разных фоточек и данных, а потом когда все будет готово, ТО РЕЗКО, МГНОВЕННО И ПО ХАРДКОРУ ПРОСТО ВЫКЛЮЧАЕМ ВИДИМОСТЬ ЧАСТИ С ЗАГРУЗКОЙ (View.GONE), А ПОТОМ ВРУБАЕМ ОСНОВНОЙ ГУЙ (View.VISIBLE), в результате чего у нас уже все загружено и не тормозит.